# delayed_job missing method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I add a job to delayed job but when I run it I have a NoMethod error

> > Delayed::Job.last
> >     => #Delayed::Backend::MongoMapper::Job _id: BSON::ObjectId('5266f28aa1cba6257b000001'), attempts: 0, created_at: Tue, 22 Oct 2013 23:47:54 CEST +02:00, failed_at: nil, handler: "--- !ruby/struct:Delayed::PerformableMethod \nobject: !ruby/object:Module {}\n\nmethod: :notify_all_with_review_reminder_due!\nargs: []\n\n", last_error: nil, locked_at: nil, locked_by: nil, priority: 75, run_at: Tue, 22 Oct 2013 23:47:54 CEST +02:00, updated_at: Tue, 22 Oct 2013 23:47:54 CEST +02:00>
> >
> > Delayed::Job.last.invoke_job
> >     NoMethodError: undefined method `notify_all_with_review_reminder_due!' for #Module:0x124781cf0>

Looks like he is not able to serialize the correct object (it is a module).
Googling around I found the suggestion to require the module in config/inizializers but this is not working for me.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had hit similar problem, and at time of writing this I have not found any other solution besides the "require" but in my case I was trying to queue the module class, so I just wrapped it with class and it wroks now.
before:

```
module GlobalModule
   def self.some_method
   end
end
```

Delayed::Job failing with similar error when calling `GlobalModule::delay.some_method`

after:

```
module GlobalModule
   class Wrapper
     def self.some_method
     end
   end
end
```

`GlobalModule::Wrapper.delay.some_method`